# Telegram bot/user interaction display in supergroup

Tags: bots, telegram

Is there a way to be able to have a user in a supergroup chat interact with a bot via keyboards (including inline keyboards) without the other supergroup members seeing the interactions?

As it stands in our current build, each user's interactions are showing up in the chat, making for a very cluttered/convoluted chat. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to show bot messages to only a specific user. you can use the`selective` field of `ReplyKeyboardMarkup`
so the keyboard will only be visible to mentioned users. and you can delete the messages after the interaction is done. but other than this i can't think of any method.

And of course you can use deep linking (to know from which group he is redirected) and redirect the user to a private chat with the bot.

Comment: Ok great - thanks for the response! I'll see if we can't figure something out.